# Only 20 of uploaded images are brought to the list view

Tags: ios, objective-c

User uploads images from the device gallery and they are displayed in the user photos (attached files section). List is not showing all of the uploaded images. TotalCount of uploaded images is 42. But the list is limited to show only 20 of them.
I think i should change the logic here.
Thank for Your time and response.

```
- (void)showPatientImagesList {
    __weak BaseChartingController *weakSelf = self;
    [weakSelf showLoading:YES];
    [[RestClient sharedClient] callMethodByPath:METHOD_GET_PATIENT_FILES withHTTPMethodType:HTTP_GET withParameters:@{@"patientKey" : weakSelf.patientKey} callback:^(NSDictionary *responseDic, NSError *error) {
        [weakSelf showLoading:NO];
        if (SUCCEED_RESPONSE(responseDic, error)) {
            NSArray *images = [PatientAttachment arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:[[responseDic objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"list"]];
            if (images.count) {
//                DLog(@"%@", responseDic);
                weakSelf.patientPhotos = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
                for (PatientAttachment *patientAttachment in images) {
                    MWPhoto *photo = [MWPhoto photoWithURL:patientAttachment.photo.url];
                    photo.objectId = patientAttachment.photo.objectId;
                    photo.caption = patientAttachment.descrip;
//                    photo.caption = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@                %@: %@", patientAttachment.descrip, TRANSLATE(@"Upload date"),
//                                                               [[DateUtils sharedUtils] stringFromServerLongDate:patientAttachment.createdDate withFormat:SHORT_DATE_FORMAT]];
                    [weakSelf.patientPhotos addObject:photo];
                }
                MWPhotoBrowser *browser = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc] initWithDelegate:weakSelf];
                browser.displayActionButton = NO;
                browser.displayDeleteBtn = [self.permissions containsObject:REMOVE_PATIENT_CHART_IMAGE_ATTACHMENT];
                browser.displayNavArrows = YES;
                browser.alwaysShowControls = NO;
                browser.zoomPhotosToFill = YES;
                browser.displaySelectionButtons = YES;

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_7_0
                browser.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
#endif
                browser.enableGrid = YES;
                browser.startOnGrid = YES;
                browser.enableSwipeToDismiss = YES;
                [browser setCurrentPhotoIndex:0];
                //                browser.thumbPhotos = photos;
                [weakSelf.selectedImages removeAllObjects];
                [weakSelf.navigationController pushViewController:browser animated:YES];
                weakSelf.searchParameters.start = @(weakSelf.patientPhotos.count);
            } else {
                ALERT(TRANSLATE(@"Patient has not images"));
            }

        } else {
            [[RestClient sharedClient] showErrorMessage:responseDic];
        }
    }];




}
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: I was to create a recursive logic so that it brings images until created images equal user uploaded images.